# Dynamic JFrame in java

Tags: dynamic, jframe

I have a project and I need to know how to adding a component in a JFrame when pressing a JButton.
I have added a panel into panel by this code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    colorPanel color0=new colorPanel();
    color0.setBounds(5,150+nb,300,120);
    color0.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.getContentPane().add(color0);
    this.validate();

    System.out.println("add couleur:"+nb);
    nb+=50;
}
```

It works but the problem is that the component is deleted when I maximize or minimize the JFrame.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your implementation of colorPanel?

Comment: It's a panel containing a jlabel and a jcombobox who havbe his data from the database

Answer (score 0):

When you resize your Jframe, a repaint() & paint() methods are called which probably erases your component.

Comment: How can I prevent this two methods?
Thanks